# c# ChineseLunisolarCalendar Solar term point

Tags: c#, calendar, astronomy, chinese-locale

I try to calculate the [chinese public holiday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_China) Qingming (Tomb-Sweeping Day) in GregorianCalendar. I know it is on the 5th [solar term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_term).

Is an easy way to get this information over the [ChineseLunisolarCalendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.chineselunisolarcalendar(v=vs.110).aspx) class or i need to caclulate the Sun's ecliptical longitude 15°?

```
//Qingming (Tomb-Sweeping Day)
2014.04.05
2015.04.05
2016.04.04
2017.04.04
2018.04.05
```

I am search a simple way

```
var chineseCalendar = new ChineseLunisolarCalendar();
//var qingmingFestival = chineseCalendar.GetSolarTerm(2017, 5); //<-- like this
```